# How to compare Hexadecimal values in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with HEXADECIMAL values and I want to do a comparison with other HEXADECIMAL value like below but I am getting inaccurate results

```
SELECT vc_vin_vis_start_range FROM ok_dc.gms3_vc_mme_vin_si_detail
   WHERE TO_NUMBER(vc_vin_vis_start_range) >= TO_NUMBER('100001');
```

Is there a way to compare two HEXADECIMAL values in a query.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do all numbers in the column `vc_vin_vis_start_range` have the exact same size (digits)? How many?

Comment: @TheImpaler the size varies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TO_NUMBER( hex_value, , 'xxxxxxxxxx' )` (where the number of `x`s is the maximum length of your hexadecimal `VARCHAR2` column):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ok_dc.gms3_vc_mme_vin_si_detail ( vc_vin_vis_start_range ) AS
  SELECT '1'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FFFFF'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '100001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '100002' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL     FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT vc_vin_vis_start_range
FROM ok_dc.gms3_vc_mme_vin_si_detail
WHERE TO_NUMBER(vc_vin_vis_start_range, 'xxxxxxxxxx') >= TO_NUMBER('100001', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
```

**Output**:

```
VC_VIN_VIS_START_RANGE
----------------------
100001
100002
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column `vc_vin_vis_start_range` does not have null values, then I would do:

```
SELECT vc_vin_vis_start_range FROM ok_dc.gms3_vc_mme_vin_si_detail
   WHERE TO_NUMBER(vc_vin_vis_start_range, 
                   rpad('x', length(vc_vin_vis_start_range) , 'x'))
      >= TO_NUMBER('100001', 'xxxxxx');
```

The `rpad()` function builds an hex format according to the each value you want to convert.

Comment: thank you so much. Looks like both the solutions are working

Comment: I am accepting the other solution only because it is easy to create a functional index on it.  Really appreciate your time. Thanks..